# Hibernate validation annotations on fields or constructor or both?

Tags: java, hibernate, bean-validation

Is it better to have validation annotations only on the fields to avoid clutter, e.g.

```
public class Foo {

    @NotNull
    private Bar bar;

    @NotNull
    private Baz baz;

    public Foo(Bar bar, Baz baz) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

or is it better to have the validation annotations also on the constructor:

```
public class Foo {

    @NotNull
    private Bar bar;

    @NotNull
    private Baz baz;

    public Foo(
        @NotNull Bar bar,
        @NotNull Baz baz
    ) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem to make any difference when I actually run it.

Comment: I don't think it will evaluate annotations on the constructor. Did you try with annotations only on the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Only in the fields, I have also seen some people put them in getter methods.
In the examples I have never seen annotations in the constructor.

http://www.techferry.com/articles/hibernate-jpa-annotations.html
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/pdf/